# create function to name objects in R using existing character vector

Tags: r

I am trying to master building functions in R.  Say I have a data frame or data.table,

```
dummy <- df(y, x, a, b, who)
```

Where the vector "who" is like so,

```
who <- c("Joseph", "Kim", "Billy")
```

I would like to use the character vector to perform various regression models and name the outputs and their summary statistics.  So for the entry, "Billy" in the vector above, I would like something like this:

```
function() {
ols.reg.Billy <- lm(y ~ x + a + b, data = dummy[dummy$who == "Billy"])
dw.Billy <- dwtest(ols.reg.Billy)

output.Billy <- list(ols.reg.Billy, dw.Billy)
return(output.Billy)
}
```

But for 500 different entries of the who vector above.

Is there some way to do this?  What's the most efficient way? I keep getting errors and I feel I am seriously missing something.  Is there some way to use paste?

Comment: Maybe `?lapply`

Comment: Use lists, not individual variables. Check out [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) for a discussion of why you should bd using named lists rather than custom-named variables.

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this doesn't solve it, please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610). It makes it easier to help you.

```
library(lmtest)
    outputs <- lapply(who, function(name) {
        ols.reg <- lm(y ~ x + a + b, data = dummy[dummy$who == name])
        dw <- dwtest(ols.reg)
        output <- paste(c("ols.reg","dw"), name, sep = "_")
        return(output)
    })
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot it's intuitive.  What if I wanted to name the two elements in the list(ols.reg, dw) according to each value of "who"?

Comment: You can add names to the list with the name of the current "who" value before returning it. I updated the solution.

Answer (score 2):

**1) Map** Using the built in CO2 data set suppose we wish to regress uptake on conc separately for each Type.  Note that this names the components by the Type.

```
Map(function(x) lm(uptake ~ conc, CO2, subset = Type == x), levels(CO2$Type))
```

giving this two component list (one component for each level of Type -- Quebec and Mississauga) -- continued after output.

```
$Quebec

Call:
lm(formula = uptake ~ conc, data = CO2, subset = Type == x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         conc  
   23.50304      0.02308  


$Mississippi

Call:
lm(formula = uptake ~ conc, data = CO2, subset = Type == x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         conc  
   15.49754      0.01238
```

**2) Map/do.call** We may wish to not only name the components using the Type but also have x substituted with the actual Type in the Call: line of the output.  In that case use `do.call` to invoke `lm` and use `quote` to ensure that the name of the data frame rather than its value is displayed and use `bquote` to perform the substitution for x.

```
reg <- function(x) {
  do.call("lm", list(uptake ~ conc, quote(CO2), subset = bquote(Type == .(x))))
}
Map(reg, levels(CO2$Type))
```

giving:

```
$Quebec

Call:
lm(formula = uptake ~ conc, data = CO2, subset = Type == "Quebec")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         conc  
   23.50304      0.02308  


$Mississippi

Call:
lm(formula = uptake ~ conc, data = CO2, subset = Type == "Mississippi")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         conc  
   15.49754      0.01238
```

**3) lmList** The nlme package has lmList for doing this:

```
library(nlme)
lmList(uptake ~ conc | Type, CO2, pool = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
Call:
  Model: uptake ~ conc | Type 
   Data: CO2 

Coefficients:
            (Intercept)       conc
Quebec         23.50304 0.02308005
Mississippi    15.49754 0.01238113
```